# How to refresh Materialized view every workday?

Tags: oracle, plsql, materialized-views

I would like to refresh materialized view every day from monday to friday at 5 am. As far as now I've wrote something like this:

```
create materialized view bla refresh start with round(sysdate)+5/24 next trunc(least(next_day(sysdate,'monday'),Next_day(sysdate,'tuesday'),next_day(sysdate,'wednesday'),next_day(sysdate,'thursday'),next_day(sysdate,'friday')))+5/24 as select * from bla@bla;
```

but it doesn't work as it should, when I've created this on friday, it refresh only on saturday and that's it. Do I have to somehow clarify what is the day of creating procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well basically it is working now. It must have been some issue with oracle.